Why does this function change pd.DataFrame in place?
In place changes is still always a bit weird for me. This is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def sort_variantsdf(variantdf):

    variantdf['variantindex'] = variantdf.index
    variantdf[['chrom', 'pos', 'ref', 'alt_tmp']] = variantdf['variant'].str.split('_', expand=True)
    variantdf['alt'] = np.where(variantdf.alt_tmp.isna(),
                                variantdf.ref,
                                variantdf.alt_tmp)
    variantdf['ref'] = np.where(variantdf.alt_tmp.isna(),
                                variantdf.alt_tmp,
                                variantdf.ref)
    variantdf = variantdf.drop('alt_tmp', axis='columns')
    variantdf['pos'] = variantdf['pos'].astype('int64')
    variantdf = variantdf.sort_values(['chrom', 'pos', 'ref', 'alt'])
    variantdf = variantdf.drop(['chrom', 'pos', 'ref', 'alt'], axis='columns')

    return variantdf


def resort_variantsdf(variantdf_sorted):
    return variantdf_sorted.sort_values('variantindex').drop('variantindex', axis='columns')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vars = pd.DataFrame({'variant': ['1_100_A_C', '2_300_A_C', '3_300_C', '2_200_C']})

    vars_sorted = sort_variantsdf(vars)
    vars_resorted = resort_variantsdf(vars_sorted)

    print(vars)
    print()
    print(vars_sorted)
    print()
    print(vars_resorted)
    print()
    print(vars.equals(vars_resorted))

leading to this output:
     variant  variantindex chrom  pos   ref alt_tmp alt
0  1_100_A_C             0     1  100     A       C   C
1  2_300_A_C             1     2  300     A       C   C
2    3_300_C             2     3  300  None    None   C
3    2_200_C             3     2  200  None    None   C

     variant  variantindex
0  1_100_A_C             0
3    2_200_C             3
1  2_300_A_C             1
2    3_300_C             2

     variant
0  1_100_A_C
1  2_300_A_C
2    3_300_C
3    2_200_C

False

Adding a variantdf = variantdf_orig.copy() (and changing the argument name to variantdf_orig) solves this. I still thought since it's a new variable name in the function, this should not change anything in place. And the big question for me is:
Why does it only change till the part before the first .drop?
Also, if I make a similar function with Polars and also assign the old variable name to the new, this does not change anything in place:
def sort_variantsdf(variantdf):

    variantdf = variantdf.with_row_index(
        'variantindex'
    ).with_columns(
        pl.col('variant')
        .str.split_exact('_', 3)
        .struct.rename_fields(['chrom', 'pos', 'ref', 'alt_tmp'])
        .alias('fields')
    ).unnest(
        'fields'
    ).with_columns(
        alt = pl.when(pl.col('alt_tmp').is_null()).then(pl.col('ref')).otherwise(pl.col('alt_tmp')),
        ref = pl.when(pl.col('alt_tmp').is_null()).then('alt_tmp').otherwise(pl.col('ref'))
    ).drop(
        'alt_tmp'
    ).with_columns(
        pl.col('pos').cast(pl.Int64)
    ).sort(
        'chrom', 'pos', 'ref', 'alt'
    ).drop(
        'chrom', 'pos', 'ref', 'alt'
    )


Please make a [mre]. This is way more code than necessary to demonstrate the problem.

variantdf is not defined. That seems to be a typo, where the param should be called variantdf instead of variantdf_orig.

Possible duplicate: Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?

@wjandrea: Sorry, that’s a copy paste error. When executing the code the arg was of course variantdf.

One of my first observation is that your sort_variantsdf() function has an input argument called variantdf_orig. But, inside the function definition, you don't use that at all - instead, you are processing a different variable called variantdf. That is why when you add variantdf = variantdf_orig.copy() (I'm assuming on the first line of the sort_variantsdf() function), it works properly.
If I were you, I'd replace the line
def sort_variantsdf(variantdf_orig):

with
def sort_variantsdf(variantdf):

I am not sure if this answer your question but it might be worth a try.

Ah, Sorry. Forgot to adjust this. If I don’t use .copy(), the input arg is of course variantdf and not variantdf_orig.
